# How to configure Ubuntu 10.x to use a different window manager?

Tags: 10.04, window-manager

I want to try switching to either Fluxbox or Blackbox as my window manager, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

What are the steps to configuring Ubuntu to use a different window manager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Install your Window Manager  (ie Flubox from the Universe Repository)
- Log out
- In the GDM, Fluxbox should appear in your session menu

Each time you want to change your window manager, just log out and open a new session with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to keep the GNOME desktop but change the default
`metacity`/`compiz` window manager, the simplest way is to create a
file `.gnomerc` in your home directory with these contents:

```
#! /bin/sh

WINDOW_MANAGER=name-of-new-window-manager-command
export WINDOW_MANAGER
```

To be safe, ensure that the window manager can run and is
configured correctly (using the log out / log in
method in Bubblegum's answer), before making this change.